# "projectname.styles.css" refers to which file?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Which file does Projectname.styles.css actually load? the project's site.css or which file?

```
<link href="Projectname.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Not sure in which file I have to put my styles to make it referenced like that. If it is the same file as site.css, then why not just referring as "_content/css/site.css"?

Answer (score 3):

It is all the scoped css classes from your app, for isolation. Note the unique identifier after each class name. The comments in the file say what components they are from. For example the css classes from `MainLayout.razor.css` will be in there.

Comment: So this is a collection/common identifyer to get all scoped css definitions?

Answer (score 1):

These projectname.styles.css files end up in your obj folder. It's the isolated css that's nested under (some of) your .cshtml files. Creating a new web project will typically generate a project that has _Layout.cshtml.css under your Layout.cshtml.

[More info about css isolation.](https://dotnetthoughts.net/css-isolation-in-aspnet-core-mvc6/)